# ng2-test-seed cannot stat - no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to follow a angular2 seed project but I do not get far.

https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed

Executing

```
npm run build
```

leads to this error

```
cp: cannot stat ‘src/{index.html,styles.css,system-config.js}’: No such file or directory
```

I have updated my nodejs to v6.3.1
and my npm to 3.10.3

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my version of npm and nodejs seems to be the curly bracketed copy command in the packages json.

This is the script part in the orginal packages json

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install --ambient",
    "clean": "rimraf built/",
    "copy": "cp src/{index.html,styles.css,system-config.js} built/",
    "copytemplates": "cp src/app/{*.html,*.css} built/app/",
    "build": "tsc && npm run copy && npm run copytemplates",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "http-server -p 9090 -c-1",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
}
```

This my version in which I replaced the 'copy many files at once' approach with individual copy commands. The build is now working.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install --ambient",
    "clean": "rimraf built/",
    "copy": "npm run copyIndex && npm run copyStyles && npm run copySystemConfig",
    "copyIndex": "cp src/index.html built/",
    "copySystemConfig": "cp src/system-config.js built/",
    "copyStyles": "cp src/styles.css built/",
    "copytemplates": "npm run copytemplatesHtml && npm run    copytemplatesCSS",
    "copytemplatesHtml": "cp src/app/*.html built/app/",
    "copytemplatesCSS": "cp src/app/*.css built/app/ ",
    "build": "tsc && npm run copy && npm run copytemplates",
    "watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "http-server -p 9090 -c-1",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
},
```

This surely can not be it but is the only way it seems to work for me.

Comment: I have the same issue, i just want to make my `package.json` short and easy to read but still could not find a solution about how to use curly brackets.
(npm version 6.14.13, node version v12.22.9)